# How to insure that my "settings.py" configuration is being used with my spider?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I enabled a few options within my settings.py 
Autothrottle
Download Delay
Start delay
Max delay

But when i run my spider it still seems to run as quick as it was before turning on all those options.

How do i know that my spider is really reading/using that settings.py configuration.

Only thing i have tried is running my list of urls with a spider that has nothing turned on and the same list with the spider that has all that turned on and they both run about the same amount of time.. and just as fast.. so i dont want to get black listed from that domain.. i want to be ethical about hitting the servers at a slow pace so not to cause issues.

Here is the options i have enabled in the settings.py

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 20
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

Do i have to import the settings into the spider itself? Do i have to do ANYTHING within the spider code for it to read that file?

I want to be able to run the spider against 2600+ urls and dont want to cause issues for the site or us.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check what settings are being used like this. And add custom settings per spider too like below.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://example.com']

    custom_settings = {
        'SOME_SETTING': 'some value',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        print("Existing settings: %s" % self.settings.attributes.keys())
```

More details about settings and spiders can be found [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the settings you are using in the logs:

```
2019-04-30 12:20:20 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, …}
```